# Problems with uploading to Heroku : error parsing your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am having a hard time getting my rails app to push to heroku. This is my first app and I have set up everything so far except this. I am using the most current version of ruby and rails. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
$ git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.132' to the list of          known hosts.
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 69, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Writing objects: 100% (69/69), 15.99 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 69 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
/app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:88:in `block in       ruby_version': There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue    (LanguagePack::Helpers::BundlerWrapper::GemfileParseError)
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in    instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in   `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:76:in   `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:80:in   `ruby_version'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:180:in `block in ruby_version'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in   instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in  `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:173:in `ruby_version'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:259:in `block in install_ruby'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:258:in `install_ruby'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:88:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:83:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:49:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:47:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:38:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:15:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:124:in `log'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:14:in `block in <main>'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `call'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:10:in `<main>'

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:aqueous-crag-8467.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:aqueous-crag-8467.git'
Richards-MacBook-Pro-2:hockeyapp richardlane$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.7.3
```

GEMFILE:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:          https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read     more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

Comment: I have also added: group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
-- to my gemfile

Comment: In the config/environments/production.rb, did you change this to true:
**config.serve_static_assets = true** Heroku pre-compiles the assets into public/assets, so you need to change the config settings. Also, after you added gems to your gemfile, did you remember to run **bundle install**?

Comment: Maybe you should include your gemfile also, it is hard to tell what is going on just from the error.

Comment: OK I have updated my original post with my gemfile. Suomi- no I hadn't done that, can you please explain what this is doing for me?

Comment: when I run bundle install, it says that gems in the group production were not installed. so- I try to install postgres with homebrew and it says that it is already installed.

Comment: Still having some trouble with this - anyone see anything different since I uploaded my gemfile?